# databricks inherited method for signature error with SparkR and tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, databricks, azure-databricks, sparkr

I am running the following using Sparkr and tidyverse in databricks and getting the below error.

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'group_by': unable to find an inherited method for function ‘mutate’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

```
Data<-  read.df(source = "delta", 
                   path ='/FileStore/tables/data', 
                   header="true", 
                   inferSchema = "true",
                   )
df<-as.data.frame(Data)
df%>%
  mutate(month = month(RetailWeekStartingDate),
         year = year(RetailWeekStartingDate)) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  summarise(Units = sum(Units))
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the type of data you are loading in Data? Can you provide the content of the variable Data?